# How to link other folders to the current project in VSCODE?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode for Node development.

I have a common code base called "utilities" which is under folder

- /workspace/common/util

Under workspace folder I have other application folders such as

- /workspace/service-1
- /workspace/service-2
- /workspace/service-3

All of those applications need to use the functions in utility

I don't feel like to create utility folder for each of those 3 applications.

However, how can I link those 3 applications to utility folder so I only need to main utility in one place?

Attached is the launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

P.S.:
Later I also need to deploy applications to AWS Lambda, how can I include this utility folder in my serverless.yml so this folder will also be included when the code is deployed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and also asked a few people around, it looks like the common recommendation is npm the common code and include that in package.json

However, npm is open platform which I don't feel like to have my code accessible via public. And if I need to be a private repository, a monthly fee is involved.

I end up with creating a seperate folder in VSCode to store all the common code, then create a task under .vscode directory called tasks.json with the following content:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "copy_utility_source",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "cp -R ../../utility/src/ ./src/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then in my application launch.json I include the following code:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch applicationService",
      "type": "node",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "preLaunchTask": "copy_utility_source",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    }
  ]
}
```

Via doing this, I only need to maintain the common code in one place while the common code will automatically be deployed into the application that is launching.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to export the functions you require from utils then import them into the services you don't need to replicate code. Also it will pull in any code you need from libs when deploying automatically if they are you own modules, nothing additional to do. (For node modules just either do: `npm install 'the-node-module'` or include in your package.json and install first with npm i)

If you're using webpack or browserify to transpile/ bundle your code you can use export/ import syntax (bear in mind if debugging lambdas with aws SAM local cli - which I'd definitely recommend) it's slightly easier to set up with just using require syntax, so to export modules/ functions from the utils folder, you could use:

`const myUtilFunc = () => {return 'some utilFunc code here'}; module.exports = myUtilFunc;`

And when importing the function into your service use:
 `const myUtilFunc = require('../common/util');` or destructure it with `const {myUtilFunc} = require('../common/util')` depending on what was exported